# Correct type to use for "context" pointers

Tags: c++, c

It is common for C-style APIs that take a function pointer as a callback to also take a pointer-sized argument as a "context", that is passed into the callback so that information can be passed from the call-site to the invocation of the callback. For example, [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Here, `arg` is the "context".

Recently, I came across a situation where I wanted to pass an integer into such a function. I obviously didn't want to actually pass a pointer to an integer because I would have to dynamically allocate it to guarantee the lifetime.

So my solution was to `reinterpret_cast` the `int` to `void*`, and then back to `int` in the callback. However, I later learnt that this is not portable: [Does reinterpret_casting an integral to a pointer type and back yield the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979126/does-reinterpret-casting-an-integral-to-a-pointer-type-and-back-yield-the-same-v)

If that's the case, what is the solution?

To avoid this issue, should such APIs take a `uintptr_t` instead of `void*`?

Comment: Well, C+ APIs should take a `std::function` and avoid the problem entirely. (`std::function` uses dynamic allocation but so do many things in C++)

Comment: @immibis Agreed. But this question is about invoking C APIs from C++ code.

Comment: I'd put int to a struct and allocate it on a heap. This approach scales better. Even if you have only one param right now, it doesn't mean you will never have more.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko If I need more params, I'll change it to a struct then. There is no point in anticipating that and doing it right now, especially since it is something that is trivial to change. Honestly, I'll probably just stick with my current approach rather than doing something complex to work around some arcane standardese. I will, however, make sure that new APIs use uintptr_t to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I obviously didn't want to actually pass a pointer to an integer because I would have to dynamically allocate it to guarantee the lifetime.

I understand that your question isn't just about `pthread_create` so I'll attempt to answer in a broader sense. However, you've also focused specifically upon `pthread_create`, giving an example, so I feel the need to answer that question *too*.

In the context of `pthread_create`, your C++ code should use a C++ idiom such as [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/). If you *are* going to use the C idiom, to provide a nice balance of portability, cleanliness and maintainability in the context of `pthread_create` you *should* dynamically allocate this object! However, there are alternatives. Avoiding dynamic allocation seems like a premature optimisation; it's the simplest solution (aside from using the C++ idiom). We could drivel on all day avoiding the simplest solutions until we reach the brink of insanity, but that wouldn't be too useful, would it?

> ... what is the solution?

In the context of *other* APIs, the sky's the limit. C++ has a marvelous set of features that make life easier, yet don't introduce noticeable overhead or complexity. We should try to keep maintainability in mind when we're designing APIs...

In the context of `pthread_create`, there are two **almost insane** alternatives:

1. you *could* pass a pointer to a structure that has automatic storage duration containing a mutex and the integer, and synchronise after the `pthread_create` call by using `pthread_rwlock_t` or `pthread_mutex_t` to ensure the object remains alive for long enough. However, this seems like more work than using an object with dynamic storage duration. Do you notice how we're slowly reaching towards *insanity*?
2. Alternatively, you pass a pointer to an object that has *static* storage duration. This would be appropriate only for creating *one* new thread. This is reaching towards *insanity* in a different direction, by complicating future maintenance and optimisations.

What reason do you have to avoid the saner option, `std::thread`?

> ... should such APIs take a `uintptr_t` instead of `void*`?

I suppose that depends upon the APIs. It's a decision during the design phase. In the context of `pthread_create`, that API is a part of POSIX. I want to make it clear that as the POSIX world currently stands, the only functions that can be called by `pthread_create` **must** take a `void *` as an argument *and* return a `void *`. However, the POSIX standard doesn't seem to require that these pointers point *at* anything.

In both the worlds of C++ and POSIX, the `uintptr_t` type is *optional* where-as the `void *` type is *mandatory*. Any APIs that want to utilise `uintptr_t` should do so with this *optionality* in mind; `<pthread.h>` doesn't seem optional in the POSIX.1-2008 world, and such a change could break portability as we'll soon explore, so I wouldn't expect a change to the POSIX `pthread` API.

If `uintptr_t` *does* exist, there are guarantees that a conversion from `uintptr_t` to `void *` and back to `uintptr_t` will yield the same value, so `pthread_create(..., fubar, (void *) 42)` (or similar using `reinterpret_cast`) can be well-defined providing `uintptr_t` *exists* and `fubar` performs the inverse conversion (i.e. `(uintptr_t) context` will equal 42).

Similarly, a conversion from `void *(*)(uintptr_t)` to `void *(*)(void *)` (i.e. in your call to `pthread_create`), *and back to `void *(*)(uintptr_t)`* produces a function pointer which can be invoked. **However, invoking a function as the wrong type produces undefined behaviour**! The C standard (which the POSIX standard adopts) is actually better at explaining this than I, so [here's an extract from C11/6.3.2.3p8](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8):

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.